# how to do search after pressing enter key in core ui datatables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatables, core-ui

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmAFH.png)because, by default, search features in data tables take in real time and it makes the search feature slow. How do I get the search to start after pressing enter?

[image: table]

activate the search feature after pressing the enter key.

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmAFH.png)

Comment: Can you add your code to the question please

Comment: Try using the `onTableFilterChange` callback

Comment: i was put my code in the question, can u explain how?:(